# Does Openshift support selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, openshift

Does openshift work with GUI stuff like Selenium?

I have a python application I wanted to setup in the cloud...

If there isn't, is there a workaround I can use?
The application logs into a website and does something for a few seconds..

Comment: They are working for me on OS

Comment: What do you mean? The page I access doesn't use javascript. Its normal HTML.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the page is normal html or not. If you can't get selenium to work it sounds like phantomjs/casperjs will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use OpenShift to host Selenium Hub / Node(s).

We have official [Docker Containers](https://github.com/seleniumhq/docker-selenium), that may be used in conjunction with OpenShift templates.

Lucky enough, I was using OpenShift at my place of employment, and created Selenium Hub/Node templates for openshift using the official selenium docker containers.

## [Selenium Hub](https://github.com/ddavison/selenium-openshift-templates/blob/master/selenium-hub.yaml)

## [Chrome](https://github.com/ddavison/selenium-openshift-templates/blob/master/selenium-node-chrome.yaml)

## [Firefox](https://github.com/ddavison/selenium-openshift-templates/blob/master/selenium-node-firefox.yaml)

---

[Source](http://ddavison.io/2016/02/01/openshift-templates-for-selenium.html)

Answer (score 0):

Although Selenium Grid is the most popular browser automation architecture nowadays - it is neither the most suitable for Openshift, nor the most efficient one. Selenium Grid is storing running sessions list in memory thus making it impossible to have several replicas behind reliable load balancer. This makes traditional Selenium Grid in Openshift not fault-tolerant.

One possible (commercial) alternative is [Moon](https://aerokube.com/moon/) - an efficient Selenium solution made particularly for container management platforms such as Openshift and Kubernetes. Moon is a bulletproof stateless solution that can have an unlimited number of pods being run in parallel behind load balancer. Documentation with deployment instructions is [here](https://aerokube.com/moon/latest/).